# Linq multplie where query with or operator

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a `List<string> filterCriteria` which contains one or multiple keywords to search a column in my database with based on user selection on the client side.

The problem i have is that im not quite sure on how to build my linq to sql statement as it could have no 'or' operator or it could have multiple (10+).

This is my original query

```
var originalQuery = (from p in productContext.Products
                         select p);
```

Then based on the list i need to query 'originalQuery' by the words in my `List<string> filterCriteria` using or operators.

E.g.

```
    originalQuery = originalQuery.Where(p => p.ProductRange == "criteria1" || 
    p.ProductRange == "criteria2");
```

And so on...

Comment: See if PredicateBuilder helps you: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: It's not clear where asp-classic comes in here, by the way. I'd suggest you either clarify, or remove the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
originalQuery = originalQuery.Where(p => filterCriteria.Contains(p.ProductRange));
```

This way, you will get all items in the originalQuery which have one of the selected values for ProductRange.

Comment: Just want to emphasize that the usage of .Contains within the Where clause translates well to Linq2Sql in the sense that it is represented within the generated SQL and hence evaluated server side.

Comment: Thanks, thats works great! At the risk of sounding stupid, can i ask you how exactly that works?

Comment: @user1364791 From a logical point of view, the Where() loops through all objects in originalQuery and returns only the ones for which the statement is true, i.e. where the filter criteria contains the ProductRange of the object p. So basically, the filter criteria is looked at for each object. As Tormod pointed out, this might translate nicely to SQL. So the inner workings depend on the actual implementation behind the LINQ-query.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can use `Any`:

```
originalQuery.Where(p => filterCriteria.Any(c => c == p.ProductRange));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way of writing the same thing as Martin:

```
var originalQuery = 
    from p in productContext.Products 
    where filterCriteria.Contains(p.ProductRange)
    select p;
```